# Are portal licenses required to allow for community self registration?

Tags: community, customer-portal, user-registration, registration

I am using Salesforce Communities to consume form information from internal customers within the organization who are ***NOT*** salesforce users.

I was planning on using Salesforce Communities to accomplish this, but there are no profiles available for self-registration (see attached). When clicking the profile dropdown, no options are shown.

Are salesforce community / portal licenses required for self-registration? Can I not use platform licenses?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community Self registration is meant for external users as indicated by the option "Allow external users to self-register"

Also as per [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_customize_selfreg_page.htm&type=5):

> You can only select profiles that are associated with the community. If the selected profile is removed from the community, the Profile resets to None.

Now, even if you have Salesform Platform user as members of the community, it cannot be selected under profile option for self registration because this license is an internal profile license.

So in summary, you need Community licenses or External Identity license to setup self-registration.

This is mentioned in this [help guide](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=external_identity_login_discovery_create_config_self.htm&type=5) note:

> For Profile, select a profile configured for your org, such as an External Identity, Customer Community User, or Partner Community User profile.